# How do you call a cffunction in a cfc from another cfm page using cfscript?

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

I have a `test.cfm` page and would like to call a cfc with a `<cffunction>` named `errorEmail` using `<cfscript>`  from that page (test.cfm) instead of

```
<cfinvoke component = "#cfcPath#" method = "errorEmail" returnVariable = "myReturn" 
    description = "get list of projman">
</cfinvoke>
```

I have tried:

```
<cfscript>
   errorEmail(cfcPath);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: What is the reason for not calling `errorEmail` with the cfinvoke tag?

Comment: That's the way I test my functions in cfcs. I make a test.cfm page and call the functions in the cfc I am testing. Then I usually do cfdumps in test.cfm to make sure the functions work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do this all the time.

1) Create the object:

```
<cfscript>
    // CREATE OBJECT 
    TheCFC = createObject("component", "thecfc");
</cfscript>
```

2) Call the function:

```
<cfscript>
    // CALL THE FUNCTION
    SomeVariable = TheCFC .theFunction();
</cfscript>
```

Your version would look like this

```
<cfscript>
    // CREATE OBJECT 
    TheObject = createObject("component", "cfcPath");
    // CALL THE FUNCTION
    myReturn = TheObject.errorEmail();
</cfscript>
```

Comment: You can shorten this by chaining the calls: createObject("component", "cfcPath").errorEmail();

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Typically, I don't. I create the object at the top of the page and may refer to it several times throughout the page.   Good idea though!

Comment: Thanks guys this should help me test my functions quicker! Also, @Eric I didn't know you could chain like jQuery, thanks.

Comment: I agree with @Evik. If you're reusing an object more than once in a template, then store in a variable and re-use it. But, if you're creating an object only for one purpose, chaining method calls is preferred.

Comment: If you are using CF9+ you can also go `myReturn = new path.to.cfc().method();`